# Reaction of grignard with beta Keto ester

Tags: organometallic-compounds

A reaction takes place between $\ce {CH3COCH2COOC2H5}$ with 4-chlorophenyl magnesium bromide, followed by acidic work-up. What will be major product of the reaction? Would the product be the same as the original $\beta$-keto ester due to the active methylene group, at which the acidic doubly-$\alpha$ $\ce {H}$ gets deprotonated?

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide illustration of these molecules. Also, could you also provide your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: You will get the ethyl acetoacetate back. It is sufficiently acidic (pKa ~11) to quench the Grignard and form the Mg salt of acetoacetate.

Comment: @Waylander What counts as sufficiently acidic? For example, why isn't the alpha H of a ketone deprotonated by grignard?

Comment: I don't know precisely where to draw the line, somewhere around 18/19 perhaps.  EtOH (pKa 15.9)  and tBuOH (17.9) quench Grignards. Acetone (pKa 19.2) certainly undergoes Grignard addition readily enough.

Comment: @Tan Yong Boon: Plenty of examples exist where enolization of ketones competes with addition upon treatment with Grignard reagents and organolithium reagents.